# Explosive Nature of GARCH (1,1) Model

Tags: time-series, stata, garch

I have run a GARCH(1,1) model using the logged returns of SP500 sector indices and WTI crude.
However the ARCH+GARCH coefficients in many cases are >1. Which implies that the model is explosive (I think). I have tested the data for heteroskedasticity, ARCH effects, and stationarity all of which were present and significant. I was looking for a possible explanation of why my model is explosive and if there any conclusions that I could draw from this. I have looked extensively online for information on how to interpret GARCH(1,1) models but have not had any luck, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: GARCH Results]